# Patching a classic asp page that does too much string concatenation

Tags: performance, asp-classic

I need to fix a server side script timeout issue with a classic asp page which reads several thousand rows from a database and recklessly concatenates strings to create a humongous html table.

Should I use Response.Write or use COM to create a StringBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've identified the problem, which is always a good start. The speed issue you mention is also because string concatenation uses a significant amount of memory - I think that, once you reach the third or fourth concatenation a StringBuilder becomes more efficient.

Although I don't have any benchmarks to hand, from an architectural view my preference would certainly be to move towards writing a COM component to handle the database operations for you. You'd benefit from the increased speed that a compiled application can give, plus additional features such as sharing of database connections.

In addition, it would allow you to start building a good data model for future development if you are looking eventually to move to a more modern development platform; if planned and written carefully you may find that a significant amount of code can be reused, plus you get the chance to introduce development practises, e.g. TDD, that classic ASP doesn't [easily] support.

</personal-opinion>, obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've also just found [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972323.aspx) which answers my question.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the .NET System.IO.StringWriter class (yes, this is possible in classic ASP!)

I use it in this StringBuffer class:

```
Class StringBuffer

   Dim buf

   Private Sub Class_Initialize()
      Set buf = CreateObject("System.IO.StringWriter")
   End Sub

   Private Sub Class_Terminate()
      Set buf = Nothing
   End Sub

   Public Sub Append(ByVal strValue)
      If Not IsNull(strValue) Then
         buf.Write_12 CStr(strValue)
      End If
   End Sub

   Public Sub AppendLine(ByVal strValue)
      buf.Write_12 strValue & vbCRLF
   End Sub

   Public Function ToString()
      ToString = buf.GetStringBuilder().ToString()
   End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I know this is donkeys old but it extremely relevant to the code I'm dealing with.
can you give an example of how to use this please?

I assume you add this class on the page with your code, but how would you use it?
example, how would I change "string"&variable&"string" to this method?

Comment: @elboffor :
`set sb = new StringBuffer`
    `sb.Append("string")`
    `sb.Append(variable)`
    `sb.Append("string")`
    `s = sb.ToString()`

Comment: spot on mate, I'd actually played with it and got it working well about half hour after I posted this. The initial site (set up years ago) was concatenating about 100 times per row. fine when they kept it pruned and only had around 5 entries, but usage has increased to around 200 rows now. this script has reduced load times now from a painful 1 minute 47 seconds down to around 5 seconds. Very good indeed!

Answer (score 4):

I tried the solution proposed by Roland Jansen (.NET System.IO.StringWriter class ) and compared it with the solution from [VBScript String Concatenation by Marcus Tucker on CodeGuru.com](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c19367/VBScript-String-Concatenation-And-Why-It-Should-Be-Avoided-Like-The-Plague.htm)

```
  Substring length: 50 
  Time /ms 
Iterations   Native   Array   ADO.Stream   System.IO.StringWriter  
1000         0.0       15.6   0.0          15.6 
2000         31.3      0.0    15.6         31.3 
3000         109.4     15.6   15.6         46.9 
4000         279.3     17.6   13.7         64.5 
5000         388.7     15.6   15.6         78.1 
6000         625.0     13.7   33.2         91.8 
7000         765.6     31.3   31.3         93.8 
8000         935.5     31.3   31.3         125.0 
9000         1,123.0   31.3   46.9         125.0 
10000        1,607.4   29.3   46.9         156.3
```

Another test using a longer average string.

```
Substring length: 400 
  Time /ms 
Iterations   Native   Array   ADO.Stream   System.IO.StringWriter  
1000         93.8     0.0     0.0          31.3 
2000         716.8    17.6    107.4        31.3 
3000         1,857.4  15.6    341.8        64.5 
4000         3,447.3  15.6    669.9        62.5 
5000         -        31.3    1,091.8      93.8 
6000         -        15.6    1,623.0      109.4 
7000         -        29.3    2,201.2      109.4 
8000         -        46.9    2,837.9      142.6 
9000         -        29.3    3,636.7      154.3 
10000        -        46.9    4,492.2      171.9
```

The array solution is still the best in my opinion, with StringWriter a close second, because in real life we tend to deal with shorter strings concatenation. I have a few pages (classic ASP I still maintain) that spit out between 0 and 30,000 rows depending on user queries. Results are in a narrow table of rows with an avg of 400 chars per TR rows. I ran these test on my actual intranet server; I don't have admin on the OS so I don't know it's specs.

---

As requested here is my test code:

file code.asp

```
<%
'Format the time for display as ms
Function FormatMS(Value)
    FormatMS = FormatNumber(1000 * Value, 1)
End Function


'-------------------------------------------
'String concatenation class (using an array)
'-------------------------------------------
'Written by Marcus Tucker, July 2004
'http://marcustucker.com
'-------------------------------------------
Class StrConCatArray
    Private StringCounter
    Private StringArray()
    Private StringLength

    'called at creation of instance
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        StringCounter = 0
        InitStringLength = 128
        ReDim StringArray(InitStringLength - 1)
        StringLength = InitStringLength
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        Erase StringArray
    End Sub

    'add new string to array
    Public Sub Add(byref NewString)
        StringArray(StringCounter) = NewString
        StringCounter = StringCounter + 1

        'ReDim array if necessary
        If StringCounter MOD StringLength = 0 Then
            'redimension
            ReDim Preserve StringArray(StringCounter + StringLength - 1)

            'double the size of the array next time
            StringLength = StringLength * 2
        End If
    End Sub

    'return the concatenated string
    Public Property Get Value
        Value = Join(StringArray, "")
    End Property

    'resets array
    Public Function Clear()
        StringCounter = 0

        Redim StringArray(InitStringLength - 1)
        StringLength = InitStringLength
    End Function
End Class


'-------------------------------------------
'String concatenation class (using a stream)
'-------------------------------------------
'Written by Marcus Tucker, July 2004
'http://marcustucker.com
'-------------------------------------------
Class StrConCatStream
    Private Stream
    Private StringArray()
    Private StringLength

    'called at creation of instance
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set Stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        Stream.Type = 2 'Text
        Stream.Open
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        Stream.Close
        Set Stream = Nothing
    End Sub

    'add new string to array
    Public Sub Add(byref NewString)
        Stream.WriteText NewString
    End Sub

    'return the concatenated string
    Public Property Get Value
        Stream.Position = 0
        Value = Stream.ReadText()
    End Property

    'resets class
    Public Function Clear()
        StringCounter = 0
        Stream.Position = 0
        Call Stream.SetEOS()
    End Function
End Class

' using  .NET System.IO.StringWriter class
Class StringBuffer

   Private buf

   Private Sub Class_Initialize()
      Set buf = CreateObject("System.IO.StringWriter")
   End Sub

   Private Sub Class_Terminate()
      Set buf = Nothing
   End Sub

   Public Sub Add (ByVal strValue)
      If Not IsNull(strValue) Then
         buf.Write_12 CStr(strValue)
      End If
   End Sub

   Public Sub AppendLine(ByVal strValue)
      buf.Write_12 strValue & vbCRLF
   End Sub

   Public Property Get Value
      Value = buf.GetStringBuilder().ToString()
   End Property

End Class


%>
```

and test.asp

```
<!--#include file="code.asp" --><%
'------------------------------------------
' STRING CONCATENATION BENCHMARK SCRIPT
'------------------------------------------
' Written by Marcus Tucker, July 2004
' http://marcustucker.com
'------------------------------------------
Response.Buffer = True
Response.addHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ' HTTP 1.1
Response.addHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" ' HTTP 1.0
Response.addHeader "Expires", "0" ' Proxies
%><html>
<head>
<title>Concatenation Speed test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Testing string concatenation</h2>
<%
Dim sizes, NumberOfResultsDesired, SubStringSize, NMax, NInc, N, NativeTime, TimerStart, TestString, TimerEnd, CoreTime, StreamTime
'Set a 5 min timeout
Server.ScriptTimeout = 500


NumberOfResultsDesired = 10

' loop to test a few values of SubStringSize
sizes = Array(10, 50, 250, 1500)
for each SubStringSize in sizes
' SubStringSize = 10

    'The maxmimum number of times the substring should be added
    NMax = 10000

    'Derive the step size
    NInc = NMax / NumberOfResultsDesired

    'Build a test substring of length L
    SubString = String(SubStringSize, "X")

    'The size of the first run
    N = NInc

    'Build the HTML table header
%>
<table>
<tr><td colspan="9">Substring length: <% = SubStringSize %></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="7" align="center">Time /ms</td></tr>
<tr><td width="50">Iterations</td>
<td width="20">&nbsp;</td><td>Native</td>
<td width="20">&nbsp;</td><td>Array</td>
<td width="20">&nbsp;</td><td>ADO.Stream</td>
<td width="40">&nbsp;</td><td>System.IO.StringWriter </td></tr>
<%
response.flush

    Do While N <= NMax
        Response.Write "<tr>" & vbCrLf
        Response.Write "<td>" & N & "</td><td>&nbsp;</td>" & vbCrLf


        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' METHOD 1 - NATIVE VBSCRIPT CONCATENATION
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'Check that the previous iteration didn't take too long (< 2 secs)
        If NativeTime < 2 Then
            TimerStart = Timer
            For C = 1 To N
                TestString = TestString & SubString
            Next
            TimerEnd = Timer

            CoreTime = TimerEnd - TimerStart
            NativeTime = CoreTime
            Response.Write "<td>" & FormatMS(CoreTime) & "</td><td>&nbsp;</td>" & vbCrLf
            TestString = ""
        Else
            Response.Write "<td> - </td><td>&nbsp;</td>" & vbCrLf
        End If


        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' METHOD 2 - ARRAY CLASS
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        TimerStart = Timer
        Set tmp = New StrConCatArray
        TimerInit = Timer

        For C = 1 To N
            tmp.Add SubString
        Next
        TimerAdd = Timer

        TestString = tmp.value
        TimerRetrieve = Timer

        Set tmp = Nothing
        TimerEnd = Timer

        CoreTime = TimerAdd - TimerInit
        OverheadTime = (TimerEnd - TimerStart) - CoreTime
        Response.Write "<td>" & FormatMS(CoreTime + OverheadTime) & "</td><td>&nbsp;</td>" & vbCrLf
        TestString = ""


        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' METHOD 3 - STREAM
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        If StreamTime < 2 Then
            TimerStart = Timer
            Set tmp = New StrConCatStream
            TimerInit = Timer

            For C = 1 To N
                tmp.Add SubString
            Next
            TimerAdd = Timer

            TestString = tmp.value
            TimerRetrieve = Timer

            Set tmp = Nothing
            TimerEnd = Timer

            CoreTime = TimerAdd - TimerInit
            OverheadTime = (TimerEnd - TimerStart) - CoreTime
            StreamTime = OverheadTime
            Response.Write "<td>" & FormatMS(CoreTime + OverheadTime) & "</td><td>&nbsp;</td>" & vbCrLf
            TestString = ""
        Else
            Response.Write "<td> - </td><td>&nbsp;</td>" & vbCrLf
        End If

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' METHOD 4 - System.IO.StringWriter
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        TimerStart = Timer
        Set tmp = New StringBuffer
        TimerInit = Timer

        For C = 1 To N
            tmp.Add SubString
        Next
        TimerAdd = Timer

        TestString = tmp.value
        TimerRetrieve = Timer

        Set tmp = Nothing
        TimerEnd = Timer

        CoreTime = TimerAdd - TimerInit
        OverheadTime = (TimerEnd - TimerStart) - CoreTime
        Response.Write "<td>" & FormatMS(CoreTime + OverheadTime) & "</td>" & vbCrLf
        TestString = ""


        Response.Write "</tr>" & vbCrLf

        'Flush the output buffer
        Response.Flush

        'Increase the iteration count next time
        N = N + NInc

    Loop
%></table>
<hr>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<%
    StreamTime = 0
    NativeTime = 0
' test of different sizes
next
%>

</body>
</html>
```

You can change these as desired:
NumberOfResultsDesired = 10
SubStringSize = 100 ' tested at 50 and 400

Comment: would it be possible to get the code sample for the array method? the link in codeguru is now throwing a `404` error.  Thanks!

Comment: Code provided.  The serve is running Win2008.